# Show price inc VAT for UK users only

Tags: magento

How can I have my magento store display prices in the grid and list views with VAT only for UK visitors. i.e. if the visitor is not from the UK (probably based on browser detected information unless they are logged in users?), prices on the product listing page should be displayed exclusive of VAT.

If the currency is changed from GBP, vat should also not be included in the displayed price, regardless of country.

Is there another call in the Magento API to be used for this?
I see "getPriceHtml" in template\catalog\product\list.phtml and I guess this is where I might need to do some coding around?
Just not sure what, so any help would be great!
Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

That's an interesting shop you have. You only sell to the UK and countries outside the EU? You are aware that in the EU you are only allowed to quote prices excluding VAT when you sell to companies exclusively?

Comment: I simplified the question - I can tweak code if some is posted that fits the bill described above. We sell worldwide... Yes, we are fully aware of the VAT regulations :-)